# MS SQL to MySQL migration through MySQL Workbench breaking special characters

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm running a migration for a MS SQL database to a MySQL database. One of the tables in the MS SQL instance has bullets in a VARCHAR field. When these are migrated over to MySQL, the bullets change to ? instead. The collation doesn't seem to be an issue because the MySQL database will save the bullets correctly if I enter them manually.

Anyone have any ideas on what I can check to get them to migrate properly or does this just seem like an issue with the migrator itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running find and replace queries on both databases before and after the migration. Not an ideal fix, but it works.